# How to Use Razor Script in php?

Tags: php, razor

I have make dynamic auto generate popup using razor script in personal home page ?
I have no Idea about razor script please help.

Comment: as far as I know razor is used in ASP.net? can you explain your question little more, where and how you create script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Razor script in PHP. It belongs to a completely separate web development technology: ASP.NET. If you want to learn about using Razor script in web pages, you should start here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: Thanks For Inform Mike Brind

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware Razor script is a feature of the ASP.NET language.

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax